# Need to redirect to a fileshare path in Oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

Need to redirect to a fileshare path in order to display the document stored there. Is this possible in Apex 4.2? if yes, how? if no, then what is the alternative?

Comment: Can you specify what a "fileshare path" is?

Comment: Its a common folder created on the network which can be used by people to share files across the network